# unable to open SSRS reports from domain IP

Tags: iis, reporting-services, dns

I have developed the SSRS reports. It is running fine locally. but after deployed on the domain server it showing exception

XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: http://{MyDomainIP}:{port}/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx
Line Number 1, Column 1:

I have deployed these reports under the windows authentication . since I tried to give anonymous access so that I can access it, But in IIS I could not found the virtual directory regarding these reports. so where are they deployed ? I could not understand how it is not permitting to the Admin account to show the reports. Please guide me
I am using IIS 6.0 , SQL server2008 R2. I am totally new for the this kind of stuff.

**Edited:** how can we give the anonymous access to the SSRS reports? It should not ask for username and password.I know we can do this by IIS , but some how I can not found my SSRS virtual directory. how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because SSRS in SQL Server 2008 uses it's own version of IIS by default. Check for the web.config in the [installation directory of SSRS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155866.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The error could mean many things, I found out at Fiddler that actually I was getting a "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized". I solved this problem by clearing my saved passwords at Firefox to force it to prompt me again.

Possible duplicated thread: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404342/asp-net-xml-parsing-error-no-element-found-line-number-1-column-1-error).