# ASP.NET XML Parsing Error: no element found Line Number 1, Column 1 Error

Tags: asp.net, xml

Hey I found a weird temperamental page which randomly gives me the following error

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: http://kj2011/site_2011/nonprofit-database/overview.aspx
Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

This page was fine for like 2 weeks but as of yesterday I randomly get the above error. I was to delete the pages and recreate the error is gone but would come back again few hours later. I have some other templates

i.e `http://kj2011/site_2011/nonprofit-database/financial.aspx`

Which has the same Master File and User Controls but never gets the error just the overview.aspx  page.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Could you post some code examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with an external DLL, which created a page called view.aspx in the same folder which caused an issue with our overview.aspx. We just renamed the page and the issue went away.

Answer (score 22):

That sounds like the Firefox error page that's returned when FF expects HTML and gets an empty document instead.  Try looking at it with Firebug enabled and see what the Net tab says - perhaps you have a good header, but no html.

Usually that kind of thing is not due to an ASP.NET error (since with those you still have a document body for the Yellow Screen of Death page), but is more along the lines of a networking error...

Would it be possible to try looking at it from another computer to see if that's the problem?

Answer (score 4):

To find the issue you are having with this problem.

In your global.asax file add:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
    string err =    "Error caught in Application_Error event" +                
            "\n \nError Message: " + objErr.Message.ToString()+ 
            "\n \nStack Trace: " + objErr.StackTrace.ToString();

       System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("MYApplication", err, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
    Server.ClearError();     
}
```

You can set a break point here or  log this message into an EventLog.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely cause for such problem is security, if the problem occurs! check file security and make sure its accessible by asp.net process. ([ASP.NET Required Access Control Lists (ACLs)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwzs111e.aspx)), also does this occur with local calls on the same server?

Another thing is to check your page and make sure you don't have one or more unclosed tags in your markup.

Answer (score 3):

I just debugged this issue on my website. In my case, the cause was a call to Response.End() . You can recreate the error by dropping Response.End() as the first line of Page_Load.

From MSDN [ms524629](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524629%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> The Response.End method causes the Web server to stop processing the script and return the current result. The remaining contents of the file are not processed.

In my case, Response.End() was being called before any content was written to the buffer. Also, there was no Content-Type in the response header (see attached Firebug screen grabs). My guess is because of these two factors, Firefox didn't know what to make of it and by default it tried to process it as a an XML file.

In your situation, my guess is the extra View.aspx file caused an exception that was interrupting page rendering cycle.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpLrt.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE59C.png]

Answer (score 2):

Just for the future reference, in case people come here from google

According to this thread, there are many different reasons to get this error. 
In my case this caused by overriding
`override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)`

and I have not called `base.Render(writer);` at the end of overridden function.

Answer (score 1):

When the `rewrite` of the url in `web.config` has a problem - the browser send 404 error. Try to comment all the `rules` and check again if the 404 error arise.

Answer (score 1):

Just to cover all the possibilities. Today I got the same error, no matter the page I was trying to access, but it was a completelly unrelated issue.

For some reason, Skype loaded before IIS on Windows startup and took control of port 80, instead of the usual 17112. Whenever I tried to access a page Skype returned an empty response.

You can simply shut down Skype and reset IIS, but to make sure it never happens again do the following:

Go to:

`Skype > Tools > Options > Advanced > Connection`

And uncheck *Use port 80 and 443 as alternative for incomming connections*

Answer (score 1):

some time This type of error occurs when you have `app_offline.html` file in your directory.When ASP.Net found a file names `app_offline.htm` in the root of a web application directory, it shut-down the application, unload the application domain from the server, and stop processing any new incoming requests for that application. ASP.NET also then respond to all requests for dynamic pages in the application by sending back the content of the `app_offline.htm` file. The default content is an error message.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the `AjaxControlToolkit.dll` that was missing from the bin folder. Adding a breakpoint in the `Application_Error` method in `global.asax` as suggested above allowed me to find this out.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, in my case, I lost a ';' in a syntax.

Answer (score -1):

App_Themes folder was missing when I got this.