# Issue testing with local IIS Server in Win10

Tags: iis, windows-10, localhost

I am attempting to test a feature error in an operational asp.net website. I have copied the website to my local machine and setup an associated site in IIS. When I attempt to open the site in Firefox, I get "XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: http://localhost:8000/default.aspx
Line Number 1, Column 1:"

I am trying to figure out how to get it going. There are no llog errors???
Thanks
Abbott

Comment: Too many possibilities, but tons of existing threads to guide you like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404342/asp-net-xml-parsing-error-no-element-found-line-number-1-column-1-error

Comment: Will this problem occur if I use other browsers? This may be a known issue in Firefox: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46487220/xml-parsing-error-no-root-element-found-location-in-console-ff/46487392